# How can I obtain unmodified command line arguments to "wrap" another command line tool?

Tags: perl, bash, command-line

I want to write a script `foo` which simply calls `bar` with the exact same arguments it was called with, using Bash or Perl.

Now, a simply way to do this in perl would be

```
#!/bin/perl

my $args=join(' ', @ARGV);
`bar $args`;
```

However, the values in ARGV have already been processed by the shell, thus if I call

```
 foo "I wonder, \"does this work\""
```

bar would get called like this

```
 bar I wonder "does this work"
```

How can I obtain the original command line so that I can simply pass it on verbatim?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can't get the arguments to the perl executable before they were processed by the shell. You can, however, ensure that the shell doesn't process them *again*:

```
system('bar', @ARGV);
```

vs.

```
system("bar @ARGV");
```

See [perldoc -f system](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html):

> If there is
>                  only one scalar argument, the argument is checked for shell metacharacters, and if there are any, the entire argument is passed to the system's
>                  command shell for parsing (this is "/bin/sh -c" on Unix platforms, but varies on other platforms).  If there are no shell metacharacters in the
>                  argument, it is split into words and passed directly to "execvp", which is more efficient.

If you need to read the output of the program, use a process handle and pass the arguments in the same way (without interpolation):

```
open my $barhandle, '-|', 'bar', @ARGV or die "Can't call bar: $!";
while (my $line = <$barhandle>)
{
    # do something with $line...
}
close $barhandle;
```

There are lots of ways you can call out to a program in Perl; see [What's the difference between Perl's backticks, system, and exec?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799968/perl-backtics-vs-system-vs-exec) for a good overview of the major options.

Comment: One consideration being, of course, that the return value from <code>system()</code> is the return value from the execution of the program, not the output from the program.  It may be necessary to redirect output to a file and read the file, if you're trying to collect its output.

Comment: @atk: in that case, you can use a process handle.

Comment: @ysth: indeed, and we've even gone over this before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/799968/perl-backtics-vs-system-vs-exec

Answer (score 3):

It's extremely simple. Check out the system(LIST) variant of system calls.

```
system('bar', @ARGV);
```

perldoc -f system

Answer (score 3):

In bash:

```
exec bar "$@"
```

This preserves the spacing in the arguments.  I/O redirection, though, is not an argument within the meaning of the term (but the I/O redirection done for the original invocation would persist to the invoked 'bar' command unless you change it).