# How can I get return value when using awk in perl script?

Tags: perl, awk, command, system, adb

I am trying submit to $process the result of this **system call**

```
my $process= system "adb shell ps | egrep adb | awk '{print $1}' ";
```

but when `print " $process  \n";` I have got zero

Any suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return value of **system()** is the exit status of the program ([here](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html)). Use backtick operation instead:

```
$process = `...`;
```

Comment: Ok It's look like that $process getting the egrep adb result without consider the awk

Comment: So when calling my $process=  `adb shell ps | egrep adb | awk '{print \$1}` I have got what I need, Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I don't think perl captures output when you use system() calls.

Try wrapping it in backticks instead:

```
my $process = `adb shell ps | egrep adb | awk '{print $1}'`;
```

Comment: If you run that command at a shell prompt, what does it give you?

Comment: When I run it on my ubuntu machine I have got root

Comment: Try $2, then, instead of $1. It sounds like it's giving you the process owner instead of the process id.

Comment: The solution is to call without system like this  `adb shell ps | egrep adb | awk '{print \$2}' `

Answer (score 0):

I just found a much more detailed explanation on SO itself. Editing to add that link - [What's the difference between Perl's backticks, system, and exec?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799968/whats-the-difference-between-perls-backticks-system-and-exec)

---

What pmod has mentioned is correct. Since I have been doing a bit of reading on this lately, just adding a comment with what I found:

```
system
```

executes a command and your perl script is continued after the command has finished. It returns the exit status of the command.

```
backticks - ` `
```

This is kind of like system, executes the command which you launch and waits for it to return. However, unlike system, returns STDOUT for the command. Which I presume is what you are looking for here.

```
exec
```

replaces current with new process and doesn't return anything.

Hope that helps ...