# how to call a gnuplot script from perl

Tags: perl, gnuplot

I have a gnu.gp file :

```
# grphist.conf
set terminal canvas
#Terminal type set to 'canvas'
#Options are ' solid butt size 600,400 fsize 10 lw 1 fontscale 1 standalone'
set output 'output.html'  

set grid
set xtic rotate by 90
set style data histograms
set style fill solid 1.00 border -1
#$ cat grphist.conf | gnuplot
plot "c_time"  using 2:xtic(1) title "time to number of UIDs"
```

But, I have to integrate this with a perl script.

Answer (score 10):

You can open a pipe to gnuplot:

```
use autodie qw(:all);
open my $GP, '|-', 'gnuplot';

print {$GP} <<'__GNUPLOT__';
    set xrange [-5:5];
    plot sin(x);
__GNUPLOT__

close $GP;
```

Or, you can reach for [Chart::Gnuplot](http://p3rl.org/Chart::Gnuplot) on CPAN.

Comment: When I tride your code, I get an error `Can't find string terminator "__GNUPLOT__" anywhere before EOF at scripts/temp.pl`. Any thoughts? Thanks.

Comment: @SSilk: Weird. I can see `__GNUPLOT__` on line 7 clearly.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I igured it out. I had taken your code snippet and put it in a code block that was indented. It doesn't like the `__GNUPLOT__` on Line 7 being indented. I should have noticed that when that's indented, the syntax highlighting after it breaks.

Comment: @SSilk: Exactly. We might get indented here docs in the coming Perl 5 version, though.

Comment: Thanks. I have another question. When I run your code right now, the results of gnuplot print on screen (I'm using `term dumb`). Can I instead capture them in a variable, e.g. `my $temp`  for printing later? I can't figure it out, but I'm pretty new to this piping syntax.

Comment: @SSilk: Usually, you'd set prompt to `png` or `pdfcairo` or whatever, and `set output "filename"`.

Answer (score 2):

```
`gnuplot <your file>`; #linux
`wgnuplot.exe <your file>`; #win
```

or

```
system("gnuplot <your file>"); #linux
system("wgnuplot.exe <your file>"); #win
```

or

```
exec("gnuplot <yout file>"); #linux
exec("wgnuplot.exe <your file>"); #win
```

what you choose depends on:

[What's the difference between Perl's backticks, system, and exec?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799968/whats-the-difference-between-perls-backticks-system-and-exec)