# Storing output of perl script to a file

Tags: perl, file, logging, storage

I"m calling a perl script stored in one PC, for example with name machine1 from say machine2 using the command:

```
system("perl /CC/builds/123.pl\n");
```

Now, i need to get the log of the whole perl file executed to be stored in a say 123.txt file and created on machine1.Can any text file be opened in the perl file at the beginning which stored only output of the line executed?
Please help.

Thanks,
Ramki

Comment: There is no reference to different machines in your example.

Answer (score 0):

I'm quite new on that and I don't know if I am understanding your question, but why you don't use "backticks" instead of "system"? It would let you store the output in a variable and then you can do with this variable whatever you want.

About backticks: [What's the difference between Perl's backticks, system, and exec?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799968/whats-the-difference-between-perls-backticks-system-and-exec)