# perl filter output from system command

Tags: perl, sed, awk

I try to get a specific output from a simple perl command en write it to a variable to use in a later stadium in my script.

I have to following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;


my $serial = system("hdparm -I /dev/sda | grep 'Serial Number:'");
print $serial;
```

This generates the following output:

```
0root@spool-B-01:~# ./test.pl
    Serial Number:      9VS3D79X
```

But i need the output to be as followed:

```
0root@spool-B-01:~# ./test.pl
9VS3D79X
```

I have tried some things with awk and sed. But that won't give the output the way i need it.

For example:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Sys::Hostname;


my $serial = system("hdparm -I /dev/sda | grep 'Serial Number:' | sed -e 's/Serial Number://g'");
print $serial;
```

Show the output like:

```
0root@spool-B-01:~# ./test.pl
          9VS3D79X
```

It is almost correct but you still got the tabs before the serial code.

I hope that somebody can help me figure this stuff out and do it the correct way.

Comment: `sed -e 's/Serial Number:|\s//g'` ?

Comment: If you're coding in Perl, why use `grep`, `awk`, `sed`, etc?

Comment: try **sed -e 's/^\s\+Serial Number://g'**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are various ways to launch system commands from perl: **system**, **exec**, and **backtic** are the most popular choices.  Some capture output, some don't.  For a good rundown check this link:  [What's the difference between Perl's backticks, system, and exec?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799968/whats-the-difference-between-perls-backticks-system-and-exec)

In this case, however, backtick is most appropriate:

For example a quick script such as:

```
my $out = `ls`;
print "$out \n";
```

Will print out the results of ls to the screen.

In your case I would try:

```
my $command = "hdparm -I /dev/sda | grep 'Serial Number:' | sed -e 's/Serial Number://g'";

my $serial = `$command`;
print $serial;  #white space 

#Remove whitespace
$serial =~ s/^(\s+)//g;  

print $serial;  #No white space
```

I have a mac in front of me so I don't have access to the `hdparm` command

With regards to the whitespace removal `\s` is the white space character so the regex

```
s/^\s+//g;
```

translates to replace all white space starting from the start of the line with nothing

Comment: Yeah this works. But i still got the tabs before the serial number. Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: probably something like $serial ~= s/\s//g;

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

open my $fh, '-|', 'hdparm -I /dev/sda';
while (<$fh>) {
    print "$_\n" if s/Serial Number://g;
}
close $fh
```

Answer (score -1):

#### Try this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my @serial = `hdparm -I /dev/sda`;
foreach my $line (@serial) {
  print $1 if ($line =~ /(?:\s+)Serial Number:(?:\s+)(\w+)/);
}
```

#### Output:

```
root@spool-B-01:~# ./test.pl
9VS3D79X
```