# Perl Split doesn't split into Array

Tags: string, perl, split

I have a file which I have to read chunk by chunk (based on time stamps). So i am using awk to read between two time intervals, and then I have to process the data further. For that I have to read the string I receive from awk Line By Line. When I perform Split using the new character, it doesn't split, but just all of the string remains in 1st field. I have used different escape characters but without any succes.

My main aim is to read the string line by line.

```
    $cmd = "awk '\$0>=from&&\$0<=to' from=\"$currentTime\" to=\"$nextTime\" Output.txt";
    $dataChunk = system ($cmd);
    my @lines = split /[\r\s\v\V\n]+/, $dataChunk;
    foreach my $line (@lines) {
        chomp;
        $timeStamp1 = (split /-/, $line)[1];
        print "\n$timeStamp1\n";
        exit;
    }
```

Comment: Just to be sure, if you print the line does it print on several lines? Or on a single line?

Comment: It prints on several lines, when I do 'more Output.txt'

Comment: Are you sure you want to use `system`? Shouldn't you use `qx($cmd)`?

Comment: Sorry its a mistake while pasting the code here, its $dataChunk in real code.

Comment: For informations sake: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/799968/whats-the-difference-between-perls-backticks-system-and-exec

Comment: Perl was written in part as an `awk`-killer (not 100% successfully since `awk` is still around).  However, if you run `awk` from Perl and then process its output, you are 'doing it wrong' — Perl can manage what `awk` does on its own.

Comment: You can also avoid all the backslashes in the command assignment by using custom single quotes:  `$cmd = q[awk '$0>=from&&$0<=to' from="$currentTime" to="$nextTime" Output.txt];` — where the `q[…]` is  one possible custom quotes (bracketing pairs), or you could use a non-bracketing character like `q%…%` for any convenient character that doesn't appear in the body.  You can use custom double quotes too: `qq[…]` or `qq%…%` etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Should be,

```
my $dataChunk = qx($cmd);
my @lines = split /[\r\s\v\V\n]+/, $dataChunk;
```

as [`system()`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html) return value is the exit status of the program.

Comment: @AntonH they are equivalents.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that [`system`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html) doesn't do what you think it does. `system` will return an exit code, not the command's standard output.

For the command's standard output, you want to use `qx($cmd)` (or use the backtick quotes around the command).

Answer (score 2):

Silly using `awk` when you simply want to read between two timestamps:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;
use feature qw(say);

use constant  TIMESTAMP_FILE => 'Output.txt';

my $current_time = ...;
my $next_time = ...;
open my $tstamp_fh, "<", TIMESTAMP_FILE;
while ( my $line = <$tstamp_fh> ) {
    chomp $line;   # Always chomp on a read!
    next if $line lt $current_time or $line gt $next_time;
    say (split /-/, $line)[1];   # Is this the first or second element of the array?
}
```

Something like that. It's a bit hard to tell since I don't know what your file looks like.

The main thing is that there is absolutely no need to run `awk` when you're using Perl. Whatever Awk can do, Perl can too.

You can always use the [`a2p`](http://perldoc.perl.org/a2p.html) program that comes with Perl to translate any Awk program into Perl code if you're not 100 percent sure how to do something.