# My perl script needs to wait until the another script finishes its job

Tags: perl, shell, unix, hyperic

I'm new to scripting languages and I want to to ask simple question.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

my $process_id = shift;
execute();

sub execute() {
  system("cd", "bin");
  my $output = `pcp.sh -p $process_id`;
  if (index($output, "some string") != -1) {
    print("Information 1.0 :Standalone server works fine \n");
  }
  else {
    print("Information 2.0 Standalone server have some problems)\n");
  }
}
```

for 'pcp.sh' follow the link :

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/systems/security/pcp-149863.txt

This script works on terminal and returns

```
Information 1.0 Standalone server works fine
```

But I'm doing script monitoring and monitoring tool gets the output as return value. (It is very strange.) On monitoring tool while I'm running the script it says

```
Information 2.0 Standalone server have some problems
```

I need to get output from `pcp.sh`. And this `pcp.sh -p $process_id` part of that code is running for about one minute. The monitoring tool runs for maybe five seconds. I undrstand that I have to wait, but I don't know how to handle this job.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/799968/223226

Comment: The backticks don't return until the command complete. Any output you see after the backticks return doesn't come from the program you launched, but from a program it launched in the background. Perl doesn't know about it. How could it? Even you didn't know about it.

Comment: What is the point of your "system()" call? And what is the point of "abs(1.0)"?

Comment: system call just go to bin directory from $home directory, the others are not needed and i deleted.

Comment: Note that `system("cd", "bin");` does nothing. It tries to execute a program named `cd`, but there is no such program, so it returns -1 and sets `$!` accordingly. There is a shell builtin named `cd`, but that would only change the work directory for that shell if you managed to get a shell to run it. You want the Perl builtin `chdir`.

Comment: I changed the code chdir to /my/location but it still returns from tool wrong information.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the Perl debugger to work it out. It is easy to use, just run:

```
perl -d yourscript
```

and it will start. Then you can use the following commands:

`n` -   run next statement

`l` - list perl script

`p var` - print some variable

`s` - step into a function (rather than executing entire function)

`b 16` - set breakpoint on line 16

`r` - run until next breakpoint or end

`q` - quit

Comment: that didn't work problem is not executing. My other script pcp.sh must be executed fully but tool doesn't execute like this even though terminal executes correctly

Comment: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/systems/security/pcp-149863.txt it is given in that link works to find open TCP ports and PIDs related in Solaris.