# Call a bash script in perl

Tags: perl, bash

I am trying to call a bash script in perl, by doing this -

```
my $which_mpi = "/sw/tools/tacc/builds/carter/site/salt_which_mpi";
$mpi_stack = system("$which_mpi",-n);
```

the problem is that I want the script to execute when it is called by system command in line

```
$mpi_stack = system("$which_mpi",-n);
```

but the problem with this is while assigning the path in $which_mpi it automatically executes the script. So instead of me getting this value

```
WHICH_MPI : /sw/tools/salt/builds/carter/altd/bin/site/salt_which_mpi
```

I am getting the path with the output of the bash script like

```
WHICH_MPI : /sw/tools/salt/builds/carter/altd/bin/site/salt_which_mpiopenmpi 1.6.1
```

where `openmpi 1.6.1` is the output of my salt_which_mpi bash script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use perl's backtick operator

```
`bash -c "$WHICH_MPI"`
```

take a look at this question:
[another stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799968/whats-the-difference-between-perls-backticks-system-and-exec)

Comment: No worries I used this and it worked $mpi_stack = "`$which_mpi --name`; "thanks! which is close to you suggested.