# Rancid/ Looking Glass perl script hitting an odd error: $router unavailable

Tags: apache, perl, network-programming

I am attempting to set up a small test environment (homelab) using CentOS 6.6, Rancid 3.1, Looking Glass, and some Cisco Switches/Routers, with httpd acting as the handler.  I have picked up a little perl by means of this endeavor, but python (more 2 than 3) is my background.  Right now, everything on the rancid side of things works without issue: bin/clogin successfully logs into all of the equipment in the router.db file, and logging of the configs is working as expected.  All switches/routers to be accessed are available and online, verified by ssh connection to devices as well as using bin/clogin.

Right now, I have placed the lg.cgi and lgform.cgi files into var/www/cgi-bin/ which allows the forms to be run as cgi scripts.  I had to modify the files to split on ';' instead of ':' due to the change in the .db file in Rancid 3.1:`@record = split('\:', $_);` was replaced with: `@record = split('\;', $_);` etc.  Once that change was made, I was able to load the lgform.cgi with the proper router.db parsing.  At this point, it seemed like everything should be good to go.  When I attempt to ping from one of those devices out to 8.8.8.8, the file correctly redirects to lg.cgi, and the page loads, but with

```
main is unavailable. Try again later.
```

as the error, where 'main' is the router hostname.  Using this output, I was able to find the function responsible for this output.  Here it is before I added anything:

```
sub DoRsh
{
    my ($router, $mfg, $cmd, $arg) = @_;
    my($ctime) = time();
    my($val);

    my($lckobj) = LockFile::Simple->make(-delay => $lock_int,
                -max => $max_lock_wait, -hold => $max_lock_hold);
    if ($pingcmd =~ /\d$/) {
        `$pingcmd $router`;
    } else {
        `$pingcmd $router 56 1`;
    }
    if ($?) {
        print "$router is unreachable.  Try again later.\n"; 
        return(-1);
    }
    if ($LG_SINGLE) {
        if (! $lckobj->lock("$cache_dir/$router")) {
            print "$router is busy.  Try again later.\n";
            return(-1);
        }
    }
    $val = &DoCmd($router, $mfg, $cmd, $arg);
    if ($LG_SINGLE) {
        $lckobj->unlock("$cache_dir/$router");
    }
    return($val);
}
```

In order to dig in a little deeper, I peppered that function with several print statements.  Here is the modified function, followed by the output from the loaded lg.cgi page:

```
sub DoRsh
{
    my ($router, $mfg, $cmd, $arg) = @_;
    my($ctime) = time();
    my($val);

    my($lckobj) = LockFile::Simple->make(-delay => $lock_int,
                -max => $max_lock_wait, -hold => $max_lock_hold);
    if ($pingcmd =~ /\d$/) {
        `$pingcmd $router`;
    } else {
        `$pingcmd $router 56 1`;
    }
    print "About to test the ($?) branch.\n";
    print "Also who is the remote_user?:' $remote_user'\n";
    print "What about the ENV{REMOTE_USER} '$ENV{REMOTE_USER}'\n";
    print "Here is the ENV{HOME}:  '$ENV{HOME}'\n";
    if ($?) {
        print "$lckobj  is the lock object.\n";
        print "@_ something else to look at.\n";
        print "$? whatever this is suppose to be....\n";
        print "Some variables:\n";
        print "$mfg is the mfg.\n";
        print "$cmd was the command passed in with $arg as the argument.\n";
        print "$pingcmd $router\n";
        print "$cloginrc - Is the cloginrc pointing correctly?\n";
        print "$LG_SINGLE  the next value to be tested.\n";
        print "$router is unreachable.  Try again later.\n"; 
        return(-1);
    }
    if ($LG_SINGLE) {
        if (! $lckobj->lock("$cache_dir/$router")) {
            print "$router is busy.  Try again later.\n";
            return(-1);
        }
    }
    $val = &DoCmd($router, $mfg, $cmd, $arg);
    if ($LG_SINGLE) {
        $lckobj->unlock("$cache_dir/$router");
    }
    return($val);
}
```

OUTPUT:

> About to test the (512) branch.
>
> Also who is the remote_user?:' '
>
> What about the ENV{REMOTE_USER} ''
>
> Here is the ENV{HOME}:  '.'
>
> LockFile::Simple=HASH(0x1a13650)  is the lock object.
>
> main cisco ping 8.8.8.8 something else to look at.
>
> 512 whatever this is suppose to be....
>
> Some variables:
>
> cisco is the mfg.
>
> ping was the command passed in with 8.8.8.8 as the argument.
>
> /bin/ping -c 1 main
>
> ./.cloginrc - Is the cloginrc pointing correctly?
>
> 1  the next value to be tested.
>
> main is unreachable.  Try again later.

I can provide the code for when DoRsh is called, if necessary, but it looks mostly like this:`&DoRsh($router, $mfg, $cmd, $arg);`.

From what I can tell the '$?' special variable (or at least according to
[this reference](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/perl/perl_special_variables.htm) it is a special var) is returning the 512 value, which is causing that fork to test true.  The problem is I don't know what that 512 means, nor where it is coming from.  Using the [ref site's](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/perl/perl_special_variables.htm) description ("The status returned by the last pipe close, backtick (``) command, or system operator.") and the formation of the conditional tree above, I can see that it is some error of some kind, but I don't know how else to proceed with this inspection.  I'm wondering if maybe it is in response to some permission issue, since the remote_user variable is null, when I didn't expect it to be.  Any guidance anyone may be able to provide would be helpful.  Furthermore, if there is any information that I may have skipped over, that I didn't think to include, or that may prove helpful, please ask, and I will provide to the best of my ability

Comment: `$?` is a piece of magic perl, that's losely the 'status of the last command'. So in this case - that ping you did. 
Can you try printing what the value of that `$pingcmd $router` and try running it? I suspect it's either: invalid or the name isn't resolving.

Comment: `$pingcmd $router` resolves to /bin/ping -c 1 main, which when run from the command line returns no errors:
--- main ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 4ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 3.811/3.811/3.811/0.000 ms

Is this what you meant?

Comment: Yep. But the fact that `$?` is 512 after running it implies something is going wrong within the script.

Comment: @Sobrique - - Are the ticks around $pingcmd $router after `if ($pingcmd =~ /\d$/) {` shorthand for system() in perl?  Is there a quick/efficient way to determine what that error code means for the input command, i.e. ping?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/799968/whats-the-difference-between-perls-backticks-system-and-exec

Comment: You can probably capture the output of the ping command by changing it to: `my $result =  \`$pingcmd $router 2>&1\`; print $result;`

Comment: @Sobrique - this returned the output that actually makes sense to me.  Looks like there is an issue with the permissions, as I suspected.  The output from `print $result;` is `ping: icmp open socket: Permission denied`.

Comment: Ah so the ping is failing, and the return code reflects that? Yes. That suggests you need a privilege to ping - perhaps the `ping` command isn't setuid

Comment: @Sobrique - after verifying that the ping command was not working for the apache user, using `su -s /bin/bash apache`, I applied `chmod +a /bin/ping`.  I then was able to use the ping command with the apache user.  I also came across some SELinux-y related issues with ping permissions, so I disabled that for testing as well.  However, I still receive the same 'Permission denied' output.

Comment: Sorry, meant `chmod a+x /bin/ping`

Comment: I have also tried a few other options, e.g. `chown root:root /bin/ping` + `chmod u+s /bin/ping`.  However, even though the apache user is allowed to run the ping command, I get the same error when trying to run the $pingcmd in the perl script.  Perhaps the permission issue is not with the ping command itself, but with something else?

Answer (score 1):

May be you put in something like

my $pingret=`$pingcmd ...`;
print 'Ping result was:'.$pingret;

And check the returned strings?

Comment: Unfortunately, `print $pingret` returns the same 512 that `$?` returned, which was the original problem.  But this was on the right track.  I was able to get a comprehensible return when using `$pingcmd $router 2>&1`, which returns `ping: icmp open socket: Permission denied`.