# Perl system return code 65280 and success

Tags: linux, perl, ssh, system

I'm running a Perl script in which I use the command `system` to execute a `SSH` connection.

It looks like this :

```
$test_result = '/home/ergaconfigs/sauvegarde-configs/configs/test';

sub ssh_connect {
        my $test = system (`ssh -i /home/ergaconfigs/sauvegarde-configs/rsa_keys/key_config_saver -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no" ergaconfigs\@10.252.0.27 "show configuration | display set" > $test_result `);

        print "resultat de la commande : $test \n le code d erreur est $!";
}
```

But I want to make sure that the SSH connection succeeded. This is why I'm looking at the return code of `system`.
As the **SSH connection succeed and the file is correctly written**, the output is:

```
resultat de la commande : 65280
le code d erreur est
```

And whatever the result of the ssh connection is (network unreachable etc..) I have the same output. Can somebody explain me why?

Comment: Why have you got both backticks (which execute a command, and return its output) and a `system` call?

Comment: Because at first, i wasn't using "system" but just a variable in which I executed the command with the backquotes. As I need a return code, I tried with "system"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As written, the backticks in your code are what's actually running the `ssh` command, and then the (presumably empty) `stdout` output from that is what's being passed to the `system` command.

I expect this is not what you intended.  If so, replace the backticks with normal double quote marks.  You would then need to change any double quotes that are inside the command - single quotes should do.

Comment: Understood. Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why you are using `system` and `backticks` both in your command.

See this to understand `system` and `backticks`:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/800105/4248931

If you want store output of your command, use `backticks` and if you don't care about output use `system`.

Remove the `system` from your code and check the output:

```
$test_result = '/home/ergaconfigs/sauvegarde-configs/configs/test';

sub ssh_connect
{
    my $test = `ssh -i /home/ergaconfigs/sauvegarde-configs/rsa_keys/key_config_saver -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no" ergaconfigs\@10.252.0.27 "show configuration | display set" > $test_result`;
    print "resultat de la commande : $test \n le code d erreur est $!";
}
```