# Why is there a 0 on a new line when I print in perl?

Tags: perl

I'm trying to get the inode alone of a file that is passed through as an argument.

When I extract the inode, however, there is a 0 printed on a new line. I've tried to get rid of it with regex but I can't. I'm passing the script `/usr/bin/vim` The 0 isn't there when I run the command (`ls -i /usr/bin/vim | awk '{print $1}'`), but it is when I run my script.

How can I get rid of this 0?

```
my $filepath = $ARGV[0];
chomp $filepath;
$filepath =~ s/\s//g;

print ("FILEPATH: $filepath\n"); #looks good
my $inode = system("ls -i $filepath | awk '{print \$1}'");

$inode =~ s/[^a-zA-Z0-9]//g;
$inode =~ s/\s//g;
print ("$inode\n");
```

So my result is

```
137699967
0
```

Comment: so the question tagged with `vim` just because you `ls -i /usr/bin/vim`?

Comment: Helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/799968/whats-the-difference-between-perls-backticks-system-and-exec

Answer (score 3):

When you invoke `system` you run the command provided as its argument, and that's what's outputting the inode number.

The return value of `system` is the *exit code* of the command run, which in this case is 0, and that's what your subsequent `print` call outputs.

To run an external program and capture its output, use the `qx` operator, like so:

```
my $inode = qx/ls -i $filepath | awk '{print \$1}'"/;
```

However, as Sobrique explained in their answer, you don't actually need to call an external program, you can use Perl's built-in `stat` function instead.

```
my $inode = stat($filepath)[1];
```

`stat` returns a list containing a variety of information about a file - index 1 holds its inode. This code won't handle if the file doesn't exist, of course.

Answer (score 2):

Don't, just use the [`stat`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/stat.html) builtin instead

```
print (stat($filepath))[1]."\n";

print join "\n", map { (stat)[1] } @ARGV,"\n"
```