# Not able to get the clientRoot of perforce in perl

Tags: perl, perforce

I want to fetch the clientroot of perforce in a perl script.

I wrote the code as :

```
my $workspace_root=system("p4 client -o | findstr /b Root");
print $workspace_root;
```

Instead of printing the path, it prints `0`

Could anyone please tell what I am missing here?

Comment: You want `\`command\``, not `system('command')`.

Comment: If I only write :
my $workspace_root=p4 client -o | findstr /b Root;

I get error.

Comment: My objective is to return the client root as string.

Comment: If I write like this:
my $workspace_root2='p4 client -o | findstr /b Root';

I get output as 'p4 client -o | findstr /b Root' and not the actual value.

Comment: If you're going to be regularly using Perl to work with Perforce, consider installing the P4Perl library. It makes working with Perforce much easier (for example, there is a P4Perl `Client` object which has a `GetRoot` method).

Answer (score 1):

Change `system` to `backticks`:

```
my $workspace_root = `p4 client -o | findstr /b Root`;
print $workspace_root;
```

If you want store the output of your command, use `backticks`. If you don't care about the output, use `system`.

See [*What's the difference between Perl's backticks, system, and exec?*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/800105/4248931) to understand `system` and `backticks`.

Comment: @serenesat: Please don't solicit up-votes and acceptances

Comment: @Borodin: I don't find it wrong, as OP said it was helpful and it worked.
http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/14999/282626

Comment: @serenesat: Amongst other things, that links says *"Accepting an answer is not mandatory; do not feel compelled to accept the first answer you receive. Wait until you receive an answer that answers your question well."*

Comment: @Borodin: I am not forcing OP to accept my answer. It was just a gentle reminder. Generally I don't care about upvotes and acceptance. Anyway I will keep your words in mind. :)

Answer (score 1):

I would do this:

```
my $workspace_root = `p4 -Ztag -F %Root% client -o`;
print $workspace_root;
```

so that the script will work on other platforms and won't be fooled by clients with "Root" in their name, description, View, etc.