# What is the correct way to run this command in Perl, no errors returning

Tags: perl

I'm trying to start a [NodeJS](https://nodejs.org/en/) server using [forever](https://github.com/foreverjs/forever) in Perl as a specific user.

This is the first time I've programmed in Perl, so it's probably straightforward to resolve. I've looked through lots of examples, but all I see is conflicting information regarding the functions `system` and `exec`.

In my Perl Module file, I have tried both `system` and `exec`.

**Using [system](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html):**

```
sub start_server {
    my ( $result ) = @_;

    my $return = system("forever --uid nodejs-34534 -a start /path/to/server.js");

    $result->data($return);

    return 1;
}
```

How should I run the command `forever --uid nodejs-34534 -a start /path/to/server.js` in Perl? It's not returning anything or displaying any errors and running other commands for example `echo "$user"` works fine and returns the current username of the user running the Perl script.

**Update:**

After many comments below with lots of pointers in the right direction that I was using the wrong functions to get the required output. I should have been using array variable and backticks, thanks to @zdim for pointing that out. That solved the problem of not seeing the output of the commands that are executed.

**Corrected using backticks:**

```
sub start_server {
    my ( $result ) = @_;

    my @output = `forever --uid nodejs-34534 -a start /path/to/server.js`;

    $result->data( \@output );

    return 1;
}
```

Then another problem came to light, the command was being called but then being stopped after the output is received, after @Borodin stated that I should create a script and module with just what's needed and test if that works on its own. After creating the cut back module and running it, the executed command stayed alive, so now I know that the problem with it not staying alive is down to the Perl API I'm trying to extend.

Are there any ideas of how I can work out why the Perl API I'm extending is stopping the process?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130997/discussion-on-question-by-j-j-b-what-is-the-correct-way-to-run-this-command-in-p).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the system with backticks when you want store the output of a command in a variable:

```
my $return = `forever --uid nodejs-34534 -a start server.js`;
```

See this to understand `system` and `backticks`:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/800105/4248931