# prevent printing exception in logs in my perl script which has original DB password

Tags: perl, exception, logging

Prevent printing exception in my perl script. in Exception original DB password is being printed so i'm trying to suppress it.

I have already tried `system("$sql1 &2>dev/null")` but it is not help full

```
    sub somefunc{
    my sql1 = sqlplus -S $user_name/$password\@$TNSname $sqlfilename     $somestring;
    system(sql1);
    }
    Exception : 
    some time $somestring is coming with character like '>' and '(' so >im         getting 
    sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `>'
    sh: -c: line 0: `sqlplus USERNAME/RAWPASSWORD@TNSNAME >@log.sql somescript.sh >>> Start time:           
    Sun #Jul 21 20:33:09 CDT 2019'
```

In above error the *RAWPASSWORD* is being printed in logs so i am
trying to avoid it

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is probably not to use `sqlplus` to access your database. you should, instead, look at [DBI](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI) and [DBD::Oracle](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBD::Oracle).

Comment: Thanks Dave, But we have both connections 
actually we are using sqlplus only for multi threading in my perl script for normal flow we use DBI only

Comment: @Guruprasath: I'm not sure how that is relevant. If you don't want to put the password in the logs, then don't use a method that prints the password to the logs :-)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using qx// or IPC::Open3 but if that's not feasible try something like below:

```
sub somefunc {
   my $sql1 = "sqlplus -S $user_name/$password\@$TNSname $sqlfilename $somestring";
   my @msg = qx/$sql1 2>&1/;
}
```

and then read the output in @msg and action accordingly.

**Must read** - [What's the difference between Perl's backticks, system, and exec?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799968/whats-the-difference-between-perls-backticks-system-and-exec)